# Use queryable of Owin Users from UserManager and join with another entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, owin

I am using ASP.net Identity 2.2 and I want to join my users (queryable )with another entity.
my DB context is like this:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            :base("DefaultConnection",throwIfV1Schema:false)
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Class> Class{ get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

I have BaseController that have something like this:

```
 public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
     protected ApplicationUserManager AppUserManager
            {
                get
                {
                    return _appUserManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                }
            } 
}
```

I can get my users as queryable like this in my controller

```
  var users = AppUserManager.Users
```

but when I want to join my tables to this users I get following error.

I make my dbContext **new** in the constructor of my Api.

I have a small app and I don't want to go with DI Containers.

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts

what is the correct way to join to users with another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you want join `User` with `Class`:

```
var applicationDbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
var query = from user in applicationDbContext.Users
            join class in ApplicationDbContext.Class on user.Id equals class.UserId
            select new { user, class };
```

Comment: oh that was so easy i did not realize i have user in my dbcontext. thank you,